# BLock HTML and javascript tags in input

Tags: php, html, input, tags

How to block all html and javascript tags in text input?

My code is:

```
$pav = stripslashes($_POST['pavadinimas']);
$pav2 = mysql_escape_string($pav);
```

But it doesn't block html and javascript tags

Comment: This question is very vague, and there are a lot of duplicates on form validation et al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove both these calls: `stripslashes()` does nothing good here, and `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be used only before data is inserted into a mySQL query.

Do either [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) (if you want to preserve the HTML source code, but make the tags visible) or [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) (to just vanish the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You must use htmlspecialchars() or strip_tags()(for remove and not convert)

```
$html = "<b>Test</b> <strong>Lol</strong>";

echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bpIqOK)